# What command will create a profile for use with NetSH WLAN?

Tags: windows

`netsh wlan connect` demands a profile, but `netsh wlan show profiles` shows 0 profiles. So I need to find a command that will create a profile, but `netsh wlan add profile` only allows adding an existing one from a file, not creating from scratch.

This question is not about whether a profile is optional, it is about creating a profile from scratch on the command line.

Comment: You have to create one manually or modify an existing one. See [Add wlan profile with password in windows programmatically](//stackoverflow.com/q/35232162)

Comment: Yes @DavidPostill, and I'm looking for the command to create one manually.

Comment: There isn't one. By manually I mean you create it by using the network dialogs.

Comment: I don't understand. How can there be no command? Doesn't this render NetSH useless for new installs? My Windows 10 install is broken enough that I can't get to the normal dialogs, hence the use of the command line.

Comment: Also, this question has an incorrect duplicate flag.

Comment: `netsh` was written to manage existing connections from the command line not create new ones. Read my answer in the duplicate.

Comment: I have read it, but it does not answer this question.

Comment: It is not an incorrect duplicate. The duplicate tells you that you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: No, I already read that question/answer before posting this, I understand that a profile is required to connect, I am asking how to create a profile.

Comment: Sigh. How many times do I have to tell you that you cannot create a wireless connection from the command line? It is not possible. You **have** to use the GUI to do it.

Comment: @Krenair What David is saying is, you cannot create a profile from the command line, but once it's created the duplicate's answer would apply.

Comment: I have managed to bypass this issue by getting the sample profile from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370032(v=vs.85).aspx (that's for WPA2-Personal but you can go up to 'Wireless Profile Samples' for links to more), filling out my SSID and adding the sharedKey part (without this the connecting command would later say success but not actually succeed), saving this all to a file and importing it as a profile. (Then connecting works.)